# Create 2 matrices - sampled by rows, and then those not in sample

Tags: r

In the following bit of code I create a matrix mat2 with a set of random rows from mat1. I also need to create a second matrix (mat3) which has all the rows not in mat2. How can I do this?

```
NumRows = 100
NumSample = 30

mat1 = matrix (1:10000, nrow=NumRows)
rownames (mat1) <- paste ("I", 1:100, sep = "")
colnames (mat1)  <- paste ("I", 1:100, sep = "")
KeepRows = sample(1:nrow(mat1), NumSample)
mat2 = mat1[KeepRows, ]
```

Comment: `mat3 = mat1[-KeepRows,]`

Comment: Thanks Jake. this works, and it's certainly simple, so very cool. I'm going to need to find something that teaches me why it works at all as it appears to say that a negative row number means 'get rid of this row'. Strange, but cool at the same time.

Comment: BTW Jake - As you answered this in a comment I don't seem to be able to mark your response as an answer. Limitation of the site's software I guess.

Comment: Moved to answer with additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat3 = mat1[-KeepRows,]`

Here's a link to a blog post that goes over indexing in R. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/23/five-kinds-of-r-language-subscripts/

Another document on an intro to R which is a great read for any R user.
http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the first link. I have the R-Intro doc here but even knowing the answer to this question now I wasn't able to search it out in that document. None the less, thanks much for the answer. It's helped a lot.

Comment: I initially replied in the comments because I couldn't find anything good to post that went over negative indexing. I was hoping someone else would know of something. At this point I completely agree with you that finding documentation on this is not easy

Comment: I found it! Section 2.7 "3. A vector of negative integral quantities. Such an index vector specifies the values to be
excluded rather than included. Thus
> y <- x[-(1:5)]
gives y all but the first five elements of x"